# Xbox One Kinect and JavaScript

Tags: windows, kinect, kinect-sdk, xbox, xbox-one

I have a Kinect V2 sensor that came with my Xbox One and a Kinect for Windows adapter. Using SDK 2.0 I am able to run the sample codes.

I wanted to try and interact with the device using JavaScript and I noticed this was an option with the 1.8 SDK.

Do I need to revert to the 1.8 SDK to use JavaScript?

Can my Kinect V2 sensor run using the 1.8 version of the SDK?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use SDK 1.8 with Kinect v2, only SDK 2.0.
 
The application that allowed Javascript integration from a web browser in SDK 1.8 (webserver-WPF) is not available in SDK 2.0. Some people have asked for it in the official Kinect forum but the MS team has made no announcement about its future availability (only that they are aware of developers asking). They suggested that webserver in 1.8 could be adapted, but I think a lot of work is needed for that (I'm studying this possibility at the moment), otherwise they would have done it already.
You can read more about this in the [official forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=kinectv2sdk) if you search for "webserver".